# How to set the JAVA_HOME correctly?

Tags: java, eclipse

I have upgraded my Eclipse from Mars to the current version and installed Java 1.12 (previously 1.8). I'm trying to run an Ant script which calls on

```
<javac destdir="${build.dir}" includeantruntime="false" source="${target.version}" target="${target.version}" modulepath="${modules.dir}" encoding="UTF8">
```

and tells me

```
BUILD FAILED
C:\Users\Sebastian Koch\git\gcs\build.xml:55: Unable to find a javac compiler; com.sun.tools.javac.Main is not on the classpath.
Perhaps JAVA_HOME does not point to the JDK.
It is currently set to "C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_144"
```

Based on that I went to my environment variables (I use Windows 10) and, to my surprise, found out there exists no `JAVA_HOME` variable there, so I just created one.

```
C:\Users\Sebastian Koch>echo %JAVA_HOME%
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-12.0.2
```

I also added the new JDK to Eclipse. After a restart, Eclipse recognizes the new Java version: Project->Properties->Java Compiler->JDK Compliance:

```
Use compliance from execution environment 'JavaSE-12' on the 'Java Build Path'
```

is checked. The error prevails. The code I'm trying to run can be found [here](https://github.com/richardwilkes/gcs). I'm doing a right click on the build.xml and then Run As->Ant Build to get the error. I don't know why. Feel free to ask questions for more information.

Comment: So have you enabled the Java 12 compliance flag?

Comment: @Ramhound Yes, it is enabled/the box is checked